# MySql Update statement running but not updating entry

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fill in a new column I added to a table using this query:

```
UPDATE tbl_symptom SET symptomCategory='General' WHERE symptomCode='A01'
```

The query "runs successfully", but the column's cell doesn't get updated, and the query says that it didn't affect any entries.

(this is a simple query I am running to test out what's wrong, because at first I tried to update all the column's entries together).

Anyway idea what I must do? Both symptomCategory and symptomCode are varchar(255) variables, and I'm using phpMyAdmin (xampp). Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Try a `SELECT * FROM tbl_symptom WHERE symptomCode='A01'` then you will see if any record matches

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Wow, it doesn't return anything. But this is so weird, cause that's the code of the very first entry :S

Comment: check your symptomCode field, thats where the problem is. Maybe the entry has more data that what you think. whitespaces?

Comment: found what problem is. I imported the codes from a txt file and it had " around them so I had to remove them with a query. But then the results came out with some kind of space https://scontent-a-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-frc1/t1.0-9/998978_10203670860797098_1742947961_n.jpg  (yeah sorry for the stupid way of sharing a screencap). I edited entries 1-8 by adding a space, making the change and then removing it again manually and they worked. But when I tried a query with trim, the rest of the entries remained like this. I tried added a space with a query and then removing it, same prb. any ideas?

Comment: It is possible that you have some invisible unicode character present. May have been introduced during the data import. You should write a query to update all the symptomCode field, and it will be a good idea to change the varchar 255 to a lower number that matches your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If doesn't affect any rows it's because there are no rows with symptomCode='A01'. Select the data first to see if there are any rows that match the criteria.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_symptom WHERE symptomCode='A01';
```

Comment: Tried it already and indeed it says there are no such rows, but there IS a row, it's the very first entry.